# osx - Unable to use option + square brace shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-layout

To type the square brace on the italian keyboard I need to press ⌥ + `[`, however a lot of applications use the ⌥ + `[` shortcut. Basically the mac only thinks i'm just pressing `[`?

[image: italian keyboard layout]

Here's an example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

OS X allows one to customize key shortcuts for many applications. Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts. There, by clicking on the "+", you can add custom shortcuts for existing menu entries. This way, you could try to assign different shortcuts on those commands that use the square brackets, for example "alt é" or "alt +" for the example you have it work still similarly. "alt +" might be conflicting with other commands, so you'll have to check if this works.

This works for many, but not for all apps. You'll have to try if you can modify the shortcuts of your apps.

Comment: Thank you, but I already knew about that, however here I mentioned this specific case , but it happens for a lot of other shotcuts and I can't just do this operation for each one of them. Also the new shortcut could be in conflict with other shortcuts

Comment: well, you could switch to another keyboard layout (e.g. the "standard" US layout), but this would probably create other problems, e.g. more complex typing for characters with accents. (actually, I'm using the US keyboard layout although I write a lot in german. It's just a matter of taste and getting used to it to me).